# Node.js (telegraf). Непонятная ошибка в сценарии

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

Выдает ошибку когда нажать Button ("USD-UAH») после нее Button ("EUR-UAH»)
показывает ошибку

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
      at ctx (F:\project\telegram_bot\app.js:111:45)
      at compose (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\scenes\wizard\index.js:45:39)
      at execute (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:13)
      at Promise.resolve.handler (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:49)
      at F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:120:56
      at execute (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:13)
      at Promise.resolve.handler (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:49)
      at compose (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\scenes\wizard\index.js:37:16)
      at execute (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:13)
      at F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:337:14

Failed to process updates. TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at ctx (F:\project\telegram_bot\app.js:111:45)
    at compose (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\scenes\wizard\index.js:45:39)
    at execute (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:13)
    at Promise.resolve.handler (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:49)
    at F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:120:56
    at execute (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:13)
    at Promise.resolve.handler (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:49)
    at compose (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\scenes\wizard\index.js:37:16)
    at execute (F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:352:13)
    at F:\project\telegram_bot\node_modules\telegraf\composer.js:337:14
```

мои файлы:
app.js

```
const Telegraf = require("telegraf");
const token = "TOKEN";
const session = require("telegraf/session");
const Stage = require("telegraf/stage");
const Markup = require("telegraf/markup");
const WizardScene = require("telegraf/scenes/wizard");
const Composer = require("telegraf/composer");

const bot = new Telegraf(token);
const getApi = require("./api");

bot.start(ctx => {
  ctx.reply(
    `Hello ${ctx.from.first_name}. Сhoose one of the commands`,
    Markup.inlineKeyboard([
      Markup.callbackButton("Curse", "curse"),
      Markup.callbackButton("Convert", "convert")
    ]).extra()
  );
});

bot.command("help", ctx => ctx.reply(""));
bot.on("sticker", ctx => ctx.reply(""));

bot.action("curse", ctx =>
  ctx.reply(
    `To learn the course. Choose a currency `,
    Markup.inlineKeyboard([
      Markup.callbackButton("USD", "us"),
      Markup.callbackButton("EUR", "eu")
    ]).extra()
  )
);

bot.action("us", ctx => {
  const api = getApi.get();
  api.then(res => {
    const data = res.data;
    const one = data[0];
    const buy = +one.buy;
    const buyNum = buy.toFixed(2);
    const sale = +one.sale;
    const saleNum = sale.toFixed(2);
    ctx.reply(
      `Buy: ${buyNum}. Sale: ${saleNum}.`,
      Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        Markup.callbackButton("EUR", "eu"),
        Markup.callbackButton("Convert", "BACK")
      ]).extra()
    );
  });
});

bot.action("eu", ctx => {
  const api = getApi.get();
  api.then(res => {
    const data = res.data;
    const one = data[1];
    const buy = +one.buy;
    const buyNum = buy.toFixed(2);
    const sale = +one.sale;
    const saleNum = sale.toFixed(2);
    ctx.reply(
      `Buy: ${buyNum}. Sale: ${saleNum}.`,
      Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        Markup.callbackButton("USD", "us"),
        Markup.callbackButton("Convert", "BACK")
      ]).extra()
    );
  });
});

bot.action("BACK", ctx => {
  ctx.reply(
    `Choose which currency you want to convert`,
    Markup.inlineKeyboard([
      Markup.callbackButton("USD-UAH", "u-g"),
      Markup.callbackButton("EUR-UAH", "e-g")
    ]).extra()
  );
});

const stepHandler = new Composer();
stepHandler.action("u-g", ctx => {
  ctx.wizard.state.num = 0;
  ctx.reply("Enter the amount");
  return ctx.wizard.next();
});

stepHandler.action("e-g", ctx => {
  ctx.wizard.state.num = 1;
  ctx.reply("Enter the amount");
  return ctx.wizard.next();
});

const currencyConverter = new WizardScene(
  "cur",
  bot.action("convert", ctx =>
    ctx.reply(
      `Choose which currency you want to convert`,
      Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        Markup.callbackButton("USD-UAH", "u-g"),
        Markup.callbackButton("EUR-UAH", "e-g")
      ]).extra()
    )
  ),
  stepHandler,

  ctx => {
    const num = ctx.wizard.state.num;
    ctx.wizard.state.currency = ctx.message.text;
    const money = ctx.wizard.state.currency;
    const api = getApi.get();
    api.then(res => {
      const data = res.data;
      const one = data[num];
      const buy = +one.buy;
      let newAmount = buy * money;
      ctx.reply(
        ` ${newAmount}`,
        Markup.inlineKeyboard([
          Markup.callbackButton("Convert", "BACK"),
          Markup.callbackButton("Curse ", "curse")
        ]).extra()
      );
    });
    return ctx.scene.leave();
  }
);

const stage = new Stage([currencyConverter], { default: "cur" });
bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());

bot.startPolling();
```

api.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const BASE_URL = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5";

module.exports = {
    get() {return axios.get(BASE_URL)}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `ctx.message` есть только у текстовых сообщений, для экшенов вроде бы используется `ctx.callbackQuery`. Чтобы узнать тип полученного сообщения можно посмотреть `ctx.updateType`. Если нужно получить "контент сообщения, каким бы оно ни было", то можно `ctx[ctx.updateType]`.

А вообще [вот документация](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=context), квадратными скобками обозначены опциональные поля.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Эта ошибка означает, что вы вызвали `message.text`, но `message` = `undefined`

Comment: ExposedCat Это понятно, что `message = undefined`. А как исправить, как изменить: ctx.wizard.state.currency = ctx.message.text;

Comment: @user403936 console.log(ctx) и посмотрите, где лежит текст